# UISearchBar create delay/cancel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar in my app. As the user types any term, a dynamic search against an external API is performed..I send the entire search term as parameter to the API.

My question is, a user can type very quickly..So is there any way that instead of making a request to the API for every letter the user types, can we create a delay i.e. if the difference between typing 2 successive letters is extremely small, combine that into a single requests (rather than make 2 separate requests)

I currently use

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [xmlParser performSelector:@selector(parseXMLFile:) withObject:url afterDelay:0.3];
```

But this is just creating a delay...I want the parseXMLFile to not be executed multiple times if the diff is very small (i.e. user types very quickly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an NSTimer.  For example, schedule a timer (with callback for search) to fire after 0.5 second, then if a new search term comes up before timer fires, invalidate it and reschedule.

If no new search within 0.5, then timer will fire and search will happen.

Comment: I am sorry, but have not used NSTimer before. Could you please provide the code, based on what I have used above for delay.

Comment: Also it will be great if you could provide code with combination of delay and no. of characters..something along the lines of http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45440-nstimer-help-please.html

Comment: take a look at three20 example of searchdisplaycontroller:

https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/development/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTSearchDisplayController.m

look at kPauseInterval variable, and also - (void)restartPauseTimer and - (void)searchAfterPause method.

Comment: It seems like I have to download/include all the files (10+ MB) of this library just to get the delay thing working...Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: no need to use TT lib, I was just mentioning that as an example of delay search.  look at that code, has all method you need to implement (searchAfterPause and restartPauseTimer)

Comment: So I should just copy the 2 methods searchAfterPause and restartPauseTimer as it is